# C# Transação MySQL em classes e métodos distintos

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

Como faço para interagir uma transação entre 2 métodos que estão em classes distintas?

No meu método onde abro a transação está da seguinte forma:

```
public string InserirFuncionarioM(FuncionariosDTO Funcionario)
    {

        MySqlTransaction trans = null;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

            MEnvolvido SalvarEnvolvido = new MEnvolvido();
            long codigo_envolvido = SalvarEnvolvido.InsereEnvolvido(Funcionario.envolvido);

            string query = "INSERT INTO tb_funcionario " +
                           "     (codigo_envolvidox, codigo_cargo, codigo_contrato, data_admissao, data_demissao, remuneracao, foto, estado_civil, naturalidade, nacionalidade) " +
                           "VALUES " +
                           "     (@codigo_envolvido, @codigo_cargo, @codigo_contrato, STR_TO_DATE(@data_admissao,'%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00'), STR_TO_DATE(@data_demissao,'%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00'), @remuneracao, @foto, @estado_civil, @naturalidade, @nacionalidade); ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigo_envolvido", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = codigo_envolvido;
            {...}
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nacionalidade", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Funcionario.nacionalidade;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            trans.Commit();
            connection.Close();
            return "MSGs1";
        }
        catch
        {
            connection.Close();
            return "MSGa10";
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Dispose();
            trans.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Vejam que passo as informações do meu "envolvido" para outro método que está na classe "MEnvolvido", e nessa classe eu insiro o envolvido com o seguinte método:

```
public long InsereEnvolvido(EnvolvidoDTO Envolvido)
    {
        string query = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        long ultimo_id = 0;

        connection.Open();

        query = "INSERT INTO tb_envolvido " +
                "    (codigo_tipo_pessoa, cliente, fornecedor, transportador, nome_fantasia, razao_social, cpf_cnpj, rg_ie, im, sexo, data_nascimento, email, website, observacoes, usuario, senha) " +
                "VALUES " +
                "    (@codigo_tipo_pessoa, @cliente, @fornecedor, @transportador, @nome_fantasia, @razao_social, @cpf_cnpj, @rg_ie, @im, @sexo, STR_TO_DATE(@data_nascimento,'%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00'), @email, @website, @observacoes, @usuario, @senha);";

        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@codigo_tipo_pessoa", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Envolvido.codigo_tipo_pessoa;
        {...}
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@senha", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Envolvido.senha;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT last_insert_id()", connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader != null && dataReader.Read())
        {
            ultimo_id = dataReader.GetInt64(0);
        }

        dataReader.Close();

        connection.Close();

        return ultimo_id;
    }
```

Porém o método que insere o envolvido me obriga a abrir uma nova conexão MySQL, isso faz com que eu perca a transação que foi aberta no método anterior. Gostaria de saber qual o caminho das pedras para interagir os 2 métodos dentro de uma transação, sendo que estão em classes diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria você ter uma classe distinta que ficaria responsável pelo controle da transação:

```
public class FuncionarioAplicacao
{
    public string InserirFuncionario(FuncionariosDTO funcionario)
    {
        MySqlTransaction trans = null;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

            MEnvolvido meEnvolvido = new MEnvolvido(connection);//aqui você passa a connection como paramentro.
            long codigo_envolvido = meEnvolvido.InsereEnvolvido(funcionario.envolvido);

            MEFuncionario meFuncionario = new MEFuncionario(connection);//aqui você passa a connection como paramentro também.
            meFuncionario.InserirFuncionarioM(funcionario, codigo_envolvido);

            /*
             * ...
             */  
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.RollBack();
            return "MSGa10";
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
            trans.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Nas suas classes já existentes, você tem que modificar pra usar a ***connection*** passada no construtor e não fechar a conexão dentro desses métodos, já que a classe de controle que ficaria responsável por isso.

Comment: Certo. Em suma, a transação é da aplicação e não do código de negócio. Eventualmente o código de negócio pode avisar que exige uma transação, usando AOP, ou ter um código que garanta a transação abstraindo a existência ou não de uma transação prévia. A conexão também deve ser gerenciada pela aplicação, fora do código do negócio, o qual deve receber a conexão como parâmetro ou alguma outra técnica de injeção de dependência. +1